# Где расположен шаблон .twig в Opencart 3 для редактирования товара в админской части

Tags: opencart3.x

```
admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/edit&user_token=xpBmtjPtwnIIy2OdtS1Z1fe6Zmvjki2w&product_id=42
```

Не могу найти данный шаблон для редактирования

Это не тот: admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался сам... шаблон действительно этот: admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.twig
Проблема была в кэшировании модификаторов. Обновляем кэш в разделе "модификаторы" и все работает